# Quoting text with > in mutt

Tags: mutt

Currently when I reply to a message, my mutt is quoting using > as following

```
On Sunday ... Mojo Jojo wrote
>Hey Powerpuff girls
```

I want a space just after `>`, e.g.

```
On Sunday ... Mojo Jojo wrote
> Hey Powerpuff girls
```

[This package](http://mutt-ng.berlios.de/manual/stuff-quoted.html) has `stuff_quoted` option which does it. How to do this in mutt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are free to define your own in `.muttrc`

```
bind editor '> ' quote-char
```

Do note that if you have `set text_flowed=yes` in your muttrc, you cannot change quote-char.